# How to disable border on the second last child of div in CSS?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

I'm create an navigation menu which I will disable border on the last children of menus item as below CSS.

Here is HTML and it may have the same selector.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 portfolio-item">
        <a href="<?PHP echo base_url('network-coverages'); ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="is-mob">
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('network'); ?>
            </span> 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 portfolio-item">
        <a href="<?PHP echo base_url('network-coverages'); ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="is-mob">
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('network'); ?>
            </span> 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 portfolio-item">
        <a href="<?PHP echo base_url('network-coverages'); ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="is-mob">
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('network'); ?>
            </span> 
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is CSS

```
.portfolio-item{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolio-item:last-child{
    border-right:none
}
```

Here is images 
[image]

And Here is you can see the [demo website](http://cootel.com.kh/demo/)

Comment: `.portfolio-item:last-child{ border-right:none; }` ? or whats the problem?

Comment: @Cambodiachannel  where is the border dude i can't find you should update the code

Comment: if u turn that `:last-child - border:0`, there won't be any border to the last child of that div! better you create a fiddle

Comment: The *last-child* is **not** the last child.

Comment: Now It was done because I have another div after that so I have to wrap that content to only div.

Comment: I think you should tell me some reason when vote me down please give me a comment I will correct it

Comment: @Cambodiachannel I downvoted was because the question title was misleading (it led the first four answers in wrong direction). I have corrected the title and retracted the downvote.

Comment: Oh Thanks you very much I will be carefully letter I promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The careers link is the ***second last*** child, therefore you cannot use `:last-child` for this.

Select the elements the other way round using [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-last-child) pseudo class:

```
.portfolio-item:nth-last-child(n + 2) {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

The above selector will match all children except the last one. Requires [`:nth-last-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-last-child) support.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `:not` selector with `:last-child`:

```
.portfolio-item:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 1px solid white;/*color and border size you can change*/
}
```

Something like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamvwuq6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.portfolio-item{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolio-item:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: You answer is corrected but my website as above is not work 
Should you please check it on my website 
http://cootel.com.kh/demo/

Comment: have you added .portfolio-item:last-child{
    border-right: none;
} i am not seeing it in your styles.

Comment: or use this inline style fot last div <div class="col-md-1 portfolio-item " style="border-right:none;"><a href="http://cootel.com.kh/demo/careers"><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="is-mob">careers</span></a></div>

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `!important` if the style is defined somewhere else.

```
.portfolio-item{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolio-item:last-child{
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

If this don't work you will have to show us more code.

Since we haven't seen all your code I cant tell for sure if this will fit your need but anyways. Try this:

```
.portfolio-item{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolio-item:last-of-type{
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I still not work 
and You can check on this website on the top of menu as above image 
http://cootel.com.kh/demo/